# Blender GPU rendering error on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, gpu, rendering, blender

I have 'GTX 1060 6GB (Display)' selected as my compute device in user preferences, and Nvidia drivers and X Server settings installed following installation instructions from the Debian wiki https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers. Clang-3.8 is installed, gcc-6 is installed, and nvidia-cuda-toolkit is installed. I'm seeing 'CUDA kernel compilation failed, see console for details.' whenever I try to render with the GPU. My CPU is a Ryzen 1200. OS is Debian 9. 
The console shows:

Compiling CUDA kernel ...
"nvcc" -arch=sm_61 --cubin "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel/kernels/cuda/kernel.cu" -o "/root/.config/blender/2.78/cache/cycles_kernel_sm61_E317D1655098C1EB89BEC29AC2C7B15D.cubin" -m64 --ptxas-options="-v" --use_fast_math -DNVCC -D__KERNEL_CUDA_VERSION__=80 -I"/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel" 
ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found, but clang-3.8 is available.
       Use 'nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8' to use that instead.
CUDA kernel compilation failed, see console for details.

Refer to the Cycles GPU rendering documentation for possible solutions:
http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Comment: What details do you see on the console?

Comment: 'ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found, but clang-3.8 is available.
       Use 'nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8' to use that instead.'

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792279/set-default-host-compiler-for-nvcc), [here](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/7f4ij2/help_getting_gpu_rendering_to_work_in_linux_f27/), I think the problem was caused by nvcc not supporting the newer compiler versions installed on Debian by default. For me, the problem was solved by using the [Blender 2.79](https://www.blender.org/download/) release candidate instead. I think it may also be solved by installing older versions of the compiler.